# Wamp Permissions windows 8

Tags: wamp

**Question**

I have tried and read all sort of questions on this topic but can't get this to work. I am trying to use a virtual host to access a different folder than the default /www that wamp uses. But i keep getting an error;

```
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access / on this server.
```

I can access local host and phpmyadmin perfectly but not any virtual hosts that i create.

**httpd-vhosts.conf**

```
# Virtual Hosts
#
# Required modules: mod_log_config

Listen 80

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@localhost.com
    DocumentRoot "C:\Program Files (x86)\2. Apps\Wamp\www"
    ServerName localhost
    <Directory "C:/wamp/www">
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@localhost.com
    DocumentRoot "C:\Users\Chris\Documents\CBull Files\Projects\Tests"
    ServerName test.lo
    ServerAlias test.lo
    <directory "C:\Users\Chris\Documents\CBull Files\Projects\Tests">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
        AllowOverride all
        Order Deny,Allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from 127.0.0.1
    </directory>
```

**hosts**

```
# Wamp Server Settings
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.0.1       test.lo
```

**httpd.conf**

```
# Virtual hosts
Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

Thanks

Comment: What path do you try to access when it gives the error? is it `http://localhost/`or something else?

Comment: with this set up i can access 'localhost' and 'phpmyadmin' but not 'test.lo'

Comment: Have you logged-in as Admin?

Comment: Can you show your httpd.conf file.

Comment: @ChrisBull - Instead of adding solution in your question add it as your own answer. You can also accept it. (after two days of posting question)

Comment: @hims056 sorry, i somehow managed to miss the biggest button on the screen

Comment: @ChrisBull - Just read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq). Almost every basic features of the site are available there. And your question on Meta which you delete was valid. If you have any difficulty using this site, you can search/ask there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for everyone's input, there were two main problems

1. I installed wamp into a folder which was nested in a folder who's name had a space in so `c:/folder/folder with a space/wamp/` which i have since been told is bad practice, if anyone knows why please tell.
2. The were issues with the internet protocol, namely ipv6, so solve this you need to ensure wamp only uses ipv4, inside `httpd.conf` find `Listen 80` and change to `Listen 0.0.0.0:80`. Again i'm not sure what this does so if anyone knows please post below.

I hope this helps anyone else stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing the following block with:

```
<VirtualHost test.lo:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@localhost.com
    DocumentRoot "C:\Users\Chris\Documents\CBull Files\Projects\Tests"
    ServerName test.lo
    ServerAlias test.lo
    <directory "C:\Users\Chris\Documents\CBull Files\Projects\Tests">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
            AllowOverride all
            Order Deny,Allow
            Deny from all
            Allow from 127.0.0.1
    </directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I have made just one change: `<VirtualHost *:80>` replaced with `<VirtualHost test.lo:80>`.

Note: You had `</VirtualHost>` missing in the end.

Comment: thanks, no luck though